# Magento Java script mouse-over image in a static block

Tags: javascript, magento, hover, mouseover, rollover

Using Magento, I would like to have imageA.jpg remain the main image

but

when the mouse is over the image i want imageB.jpg display.

i have inserted this in my static block and nothing happens

```
<style>

.myImage {
     width:100px;
     height:50px;
     display:block;
     background-image:url(wysiwyg/imageA.jpg);
}

.myImage:hover {
     background-image:url(imageB.jpg)
}

</style>

<a class="myImage" href="#"></a>
```

What am i missing am? I appreciate any help i can get. Thank you.

Comment: try to use sprites instead of seperate images, as sometimes image loading takes some time.

Comment: check `imageB.jpg` path... because your `imageA.jpg` from `wysiwyg` directory... may be you missed that...

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine for me... <kbd>**[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/4YLM8/)**</kbd>

If my guess is correct, you should check your file path.

Because your `imageA.jpg` is from `wysiwyg` directory. My be you missed your file path for `imageB.jpg`.

Try this code,

```
.myImage:hover {
     background-image:url(wysiwyg/imageB.jpg)
}
```

Instead of,

```
.myImage:hover {
     background-image:url(imageB.jpg)
}
```

And let me know the OP.